# How to color unit tests with lib minitest or Test:Unit?

Tags: ruby, testunit, minitest

I would like to have unit tests output color in my dev environment. However, I can't make it work on Linux (Debian and Ubuntu). When I include the following libs:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require 'minitest/unit'
require 'minitest/pride'
```

I get:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/gems/minitest-2.3.1/lib/minitest/pride.rb:35:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `output' for MiniTest::Unit:Class (NoMethodError)
```

caused by the code:

```
MiniTest::Unit.output = PrideIO.new(MiniTest::Unit.output)
```

I have seen a working [Rspec variant](https://github.com/ferrous26/rspec-pride). Unfortunately, my Ruby knowledge is not enough to see differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of late 2023 the accepted answer no longer works. The following, however, does.

```
require "minitest"
Minitest.load_plugins
require "minitest/pride"
```

Include the above code in e.g. `test/test_helper.rb`, or in wherever you put code common to all of your tests. This will give you test runs that look similar to this:

[image: Running minitest with the pride test output colorizer]

Answer (score 14):

Give [turn](https://github.com/turn-project/turn) a whirl.

Add this to your Gemfile:

```
group :test do
  gem 'turn', :require => false
end
```

Comment: It should be mentioned, that at this time, turn is *not* compatible with MiniTest version 5 and up.

Comment: You are correct, Matt. MiniTest v5 support is being tracked here: https://github.com/turn-project/turn/issues/127

Comment: For MiniTest 5+, only `minitest-rg` did it for me.

Comment: Also, turn is no longer being maintained (see https://github.com/turn-project/turn/)

Answer (score 13):

step 1 : use the latest version of the gem (I think it will be fixed in Ruby 1.9.3)

```
gem install minitest
```

step 2 : require "minitest/pride" on the command line, not in your code

```
ruby -rminitest/pride your_ruby_script.rb
```

.. and in your code simply require 'minitest/autorun'

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
```

If you use Rubymine, just add

```
-rminitest
```

in the default configuration of the tests.
=> the configuration would like

```
-e $stdout.sync=true;$stderr.sync=true;load($0=ARGV.shift) -rminitest/pride
```

Comment: Thanks. Requiring pride in my code rather than in the command-line worked fine though.

Answer (score 4):

simply add these lines to your test_helper.rb file after require 'rails/test_help'

```
require "minitest/reporters"
Minitest::Reporters.use!
```

in your gemfile add

```
gem 'minitest-reporters', '~> 1.0.7'
```

this will get your rake test to be in red and green, but it also brings up the backtrace. to get rid of all those extra backtrace logs add this to your gemfile then bundle:

```
gem 'mini_backtrace'
```

then in config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb add this line to cut all the extra rvm stuff

```
Rails.backtrace_cleaner.add_silencer { |line| line =~ /rvm/ }
```

hope that works for you, let me know if you need more details.

Answer (score 3):

See https://github.com/tenderlove/purdytest/issues/1. It seems to be a known bug with the minitest version shipped with 1.9.2. For the others, adding

```
gem "minitest"
```

at the very top of your file did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I currently use `purdytest` with 1.9.2

Answer (score 0):

Try look at this post about using turn gem for nice looking and configurable output for minitest.
http://rawonrails.blogspot.com/2012/01/better-minitest-output-with-turn-gem.html

Answer (score -1):

```
$ gem install mynyml-redgreen --source http://gemcutter.org

# in your test file
require 'redgreen'
```

redgreen and turn work nicely in conjunction with each other, by the way